# Is periodically checking in with potential employers a good strategy?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, new-job, employment

I raised a question previously about a politely worded response, which I was unsure if it amounted to a rejection/ go away, leave me alone.Quick background... I speculatively cold called several companies Dec last year and got through to the head decision maker, who asked me to send my cv and a week later sent this follow up.

> Hello,
>
> I sent a speculative enquiry (below)last week regarding an unpaid
> position.
>
> I wonder if you had a chance to look over my details.
>
> Please do advise me of your decision.
>
> Thanks

---

> Hi Sally . Unfortunately we do not have any suitable openings at the
> current time. I will definitely keep your cv under reference for
> suitable junior roles in the near future.
>
> Best, Steve

In the interim, I have been working on relevant, independent research but have been getting a bit itchy for work. This company has an excellent mentorship prog, as well as potential for career progression. I also have to say that this head comes across as incredibly polite and considerate in responding back to my emails, as I'm sure he too busy and important to think of my emails as important (and I mean that genuinely, not sarcastically).All of this gives me the impression that this must a worthwhile firm to be part of, and supports their excellent reputation.

My friend told me it is a good idea to check in with potential leads every 3-4 months, in the vein of 'Hello, I'm here and still interested. Please keep me in mind'.

This is what happened mid Feb

> Hi Steve. I’m wondering, any Unpaid Junior roles? Anything I can do to
> better my chances?
> Best
> Sally

---

> We really don’t have any positions at the moment Sally, although I definitely admire your energy. If anything suitable comes along I will certainly be in touch.
>
> Best,Steve

---

> I really hope so and look forward to it. Because I have research that I would like to show you then.
>
> Best wishes Steve
>
> Sally

I'm pretty sure Ive blown my chances now, if there was any possibility previously, which is a real shame for the reasons I gave above.

Can I ask, in this situation and with potential future leads, is my friend's suggestion of checking back every 3-4 months a good tactic? Has it worked for anyone here?

PS: don't worry, unless I hear back from this firm first, I am never contacting them again!!!

Answer (score 4):

It is good to keep in touch with potential recruters every few months, and remind them that you exist and are still looking. However, don't be too clingy if they answer (a lot of time they don't even bother).

The example you gave sounds a bit over the top, especially in the last mail you sent them. Don't push it if they say they don't have a spot open for you right now :

> Hello Steve,
>
> Message received, thanks for your answer and keeping me posted.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Sally

The example your friend gave you is much more along the lines of something I would write, although obviously in a more professionnal manner.

On the other hand, I don't know if reminding them every 6 months for 2 years could hurt your chances, as that would imply that you didn't find a job in that time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Steve,

Message received, thanks for your answer and keeping me posted.

Best regards,

Sally. This is a great response to the communication, wish I had posted the question before I hit send. I agree my response was OTT *cringe*

Answer (score 1):

Checking back every few months is okay. One of three possible responses:

1. Best case: You come in for a interview
2. So-so case: They tell you the standard response you've been getting
3. Worse case: They ignore you or tell you to stop emailing them

Either way it can't hurt you but I wouldn't explain a very long email. Save the research and stuff you've been doing for the interview. In the email simply state:

> Steve, Thank you for interviewing me earlier this year. I am wondering if you have any opening that I might fit? Attached is my latest resume. Looking forward hearing from you.

Comment: If I ever summon up the courage to contact them in 6 months, this is the email I will send

Comment: Well don't be afraid. The worst thing they'll say is no. You'll never know if you don't try.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to this question depends on your long term plans, and those of the employer you're interested in. Checking in once every 3-4 months implies that either:

1) You've found another job but are willing to jump ship at a moment's notice, or
2) You've been unemployed for months at a time.

Depending on the industry and employer, these may both be incredibly bad signs, or they may not be a big deal at all. Checking in like that also implies that you aren't aware of, or are too lazy to check, the channels the employer uses to hire. Do they have external job postings on their website? Do they use a recruiting service? Are you aware of those channels and are you keeping track of them? Or are you expecting that this contact of yours is going to do that legwork for you?

If you DO check back in, I would only do so with purpose. Don't check in unless you have something meaningful to say and keep it brief. You mentioned outside research - perhaps you could provide some info on that, offer to share what you've been doing, or even ask for feedback on it (assuming that was appropriate in your culture/industry).

This is where professional social networking tools can be handy. It's easy to stay in someone's peripheral vision on Linkedin or similar sites without being a pain in their side. I try to maintain a moderate level of activity on Linkedin with respect to my professional interests - liking or commenting on articles, posting things I find relevant, etc - maybe a few times a month. Doing so keeps your name in someone's feed, without the need to stalk them or pester them with emails, and it gives them a (passive) way to know what you're up to.

I feel like this is as much a question about professional networking as it is a question about recruiter/employee relationships - and when it comes to networking, you have to make sure you're offering something as much as asking something. No one wants to network with someone who is asking for something but has nothing of value to say or offer in return.