# Should I re-contact this potential lead?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, employer, entry-level

I feel like I may be verging on harassing a potential lead (the chain of previous correspondence below).
I have since completed a benchmark, professional qualification which strengthens me as a candidate; potentially ticking at least one box on the checklist.

Should I update this Head, or would I be in fact annoying/harrasing him, and sabotaging my chances at present, if indeed any? Previous opinion was this was polite rejection, along the lines of 'not interested, go away and leave me alone'.

Background

I speculatively cold called several companies Dec last year and got through to the head decision maker, who asked me to send my cv and a week later sent this follow up (no interview, and I am a mature entry level candidate who re-trained last year seeking to gain experience).

*Hello, 
I sent a speculative enquiry (below)last week regarding an unpaid position. 
I wonder if you had a chance to look over my details. 
Please do advise me of your decision. 
Thanks*

*Hi Sally . Unfortunately we do not have any suitable openings at the current time. I will definitely keep your cv under reference for suitable junior roles in the near future. 
Best, Steve*

My friend told me it is a good idea to check in with potential leads every 3-4 months, in the vein of 'Hello, I'm here and still interested. Please keep me in mind'.

This is what happened mid Feb

*Hi Steve. I’m wondering, any Unpaid Junior roles? Anything I can do to better my chances? 
Best 
Sally*

*We really don’t have any positions at the moment Sally, although I definitely admire your energy. If anything suitable comes along I will certainly be in touch. 
Best,Steve*

*I really hope so and look forward to it. Because I have research that I would like to show you then. 
Best wishes Steve 
Sally*

Comment: Why are you looking for an unpaid role? Unless it was an internship for a set time (and even then, those are paid sometimes)

Comment: Seeking unpaid position because of lack of experience... I was thinking of an internship, in hindsight perhaps clumsily phrased correspondence! Also, based on previous work in other sectors such as law and marketing, a strategy that works well for me is to work unpaid initially to get foot in the door. After 2 months they always offer me a paid position having seen my work ethic. Plus this is a company out of my league, I felt I had to do something to compensate for lack of experience. Once in I'd be set for the next 5 years ... with hard work ofcourse.

Comment: What profession is this company for?

Comment: it is in the Financial sector

Comment: You may want to edit your answer to make it more clear when you are quoting conversation(s) from the past versus the text in your actual question. You can use the quote feature (explained in the formatting section above the text box when you're posting). For instance, the line *"Sally Do I have any chance with this firm or is this a standard rejection for now and the future?"* - are you asking *us* that, or did you ask *him* that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked the same question in March, [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/108230/is-periodically-checking-in-with-potential-employers-a-good-strategy)...  the overall recommendation was to keep very much a light touch when it comes to keeping in touch.  I know you're eager to get a foot in the door, however being too persistent can push them the other way very quickly.

As you last contacted them in February, I would give it another couple of months, and if you still don't hear anything by around June, then it could be prudent just to follow up at that time, and give him any relevant new information (for example the benchmark qualification you achieved), but keep it light.  Something along the lines of:

> Steve,
>
> Just wanted to let you know that since my last email I achieved [insert qualification].  I'm still interested in joining *organisation*, even as an intern, to gain some experience.
>
> I'd be happy to discuss any possible future roles with you, please do give me a call on [number] if anything comes up
>
> Thanks - Sally